# What factors actually influence ad mob estimated earnings?

Tags: admob

In my app i have a banner ad also i have given ad refresh after 120 seconds. It seems to me that the estimated earnings of this banner ad is very poor according to the number of impressions it has.Note that, My app's maximum user location is Bangladesh.
I want to know some information :
1. Does ad mob estimated earning vary with user location ?
2. Does estimated earning  depend on ad impression in a manner that the more impression the more earnings ?
3. is there any strategy to apply inside my code or in ad mob ad  setting  for improving my estimated earning ?

It would be very useful for me if you help me fix these things .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ad mob estimated earnings is not a programming related question according to the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

First take a look at admob [RPM](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3436474?hl=en) and [ECPM](https://adsense.googleblog.com/2006/02/ecpm-what-exactly-is-that.html)

The basic way of calculating revenues in the advertising world is by dividing revenue by impressions *1000

With that said there are many factors which effect the amount of revenues generated by users.

- Geo: the geo location of the user is very important, for example US user is worth a lot more then weaker states users
- App category: Hardcore apps like heavy strategy games or business related apps will usually attract advertisers which will pay more for advertising on those apps rather then utility or casual games
- CTR is very important, and it reflects the relative amount of users which actually clicked you ad. You can improve your CTR by placing your ad in the right flow for your app [Interstitial best practice](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=en)
- Off course as much more impressions more revenue

Hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

First the location is an important factor that determinate the earnings, some Advertisers pays more in one country than in others. This is because some people or areas are more probable that spend money buying some product (apps, events, real life products, etc...). Anyway, if there are more local-releted ads it's more probable that the user's click it and with that the earnings increase.

Second, more impressions doesn´t always mean more earnings, because the points mentioned above.

And last, if your app is some tool-type (calculator, music player, etc...) translate to at least 2 or 3 languages (the most spoken around the world), with a descriptión and well designed screen caps. This will increment the downloads and earnings with that.